# NSOutlineView with Checkbox in Each node

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsoutlineview

I am trying to create a folder structure with an `NSOutLine` view with a check box in each node. How do I implement that?

Can I use a custom view?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create an outline view with a checkbox in each row. With modern view-based outline views, this is straightforward. There's no need for a custom view, at least to achieve this.

Comment: I am using Xcode 6 and outline view object, but i can't place a checkbox.How can i achieve it ,can you please explain?

Comment: On the Attributes inspector, is the outline view's Content Mode configured as View Based? It should be. Once that's done, you can just drag a checkbox from the object library into the table cell view for one of the columns. It may help to display the document outline (Editor > Show Document Outline) and drill down to the outline view's column's cell view.

Comment: Thank you @Ken, I did  as u said, but my actual implementation is a structure like finders column view(3rd view) with checkbox.that is i want add a folder icon to each node and checkbox.

Comment: I hope you have experience in it, can you suggest any tutorial or git repo.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a tutorial service. You need to ask **specific** questions. Show specifically what you tried, what the result was, and how that differed from what you wanted or expected. Apple has the [Table View Programming Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [Outline View Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OutlineView/OutlineView.html).

Comment: There's also the [OutlineView sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/OutlineView/Introduction/Intro.html), which shows the file system hierarchy, although it uses the old `NSCell`-based mode.